# SQL to calculate Sum of all possible number combinations in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below.

```
`Col (number)
1
2
4
8
`
```

I'm looking to write a SQL which will give me an output as below, summing up all different combinations of values in the column in multiple rows.

```
`3 (1+2)
5 (1+4)
9 (1+8)
....
....
7(1+2+4)
11(1+2+8)
14(2+4+8)
15(1+2+4+8)`
```

Comment: What version of Oracle do you have?  And, if you have more than a couple dozen rows in the table, the output will be too large for you to do anything with.

Comment: Oracle 11g. The table will have 5-10 records

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me, by using a recursive `WITH`.

Note that I didn't get repetitions and all permutations, so the query won't return, for example, both `1+2` and `2+1`, since they are the same thing.

We get each unique combination as `Varchar2` (renamed as `expression` below), then simply extract the numbers from that `Varchar2` (as in create rows with the values split by the character `+` )and then getting their `SUM`.

I select `row_number()`  ordered by `val` such that the results will be displayed in order, starting from 1 up to last number, regardless of the order in which they were inserted in the database.

Another problem is that if the numbers in your table are not unique it will generate duplicates. So this will only work if you have no duplicates in your numbers table. If you do have duplicates in your table, one way to fix this would be to add a `distinct` clause in the query (I've added it in the code below for reference)

This might not be the best solution, and I'm sure that there are probably better alternatives, but it's what I could come up with in short notice.

Try it out:

```
  SELECT distinct expression,
         (    SELECT SUM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (expression,
                                         '[^+]+',
                                         1,
                                         LEVEL))
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (expression,
                                    '[^+]+',
                                    1,
                                    LEVEL)
                        IS NOT NULL)
            AS THE_SUM
    FROM (WITH t
               AS (  SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY val) AS seqno,
                            val AS expression
                       FROM my_numbers
                   ORDER BY val ASC),
               t2 (s, t)
               AS (SELECT seqno, CAST (expression AS VARCHAR2 (1)) FROM t
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT t.seqno, t || '+' || expression
                     FROM t, t2
                    WHERE s < seqno)
          SELECT s, t expression
            FROM t2)
ORDER BY 1
```

Contents of `my_numbers` table:

```
VAL
4
8
2
1
```

Output:

```
EXPRESSION     |     THE_SUM
1              |     1
1+2            |     3
1+2+4          |     7
1+2+4+8        |     15
1+2+8          |     11
1+4            |     5
1+4+8          |     13
1+8            |     9
2              |     2
2+4            |     6
2+4+8          |     14
2+8            |     10
4              |     4
4+8            |     12
8              |     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11gR2 supports recursive CTES, so that can be expressed as:

```
with nums as (
      select 1 as n union all select 10 union all select 100 union all select 1000
     ),
     t(n, vals, cnt) as (
      select n, cast(n as varchar(255)) as vals, 1 as cnt
      from nums
      union all
      select t.n + nums.n, cast(vals || '+' || nums.n as varchar(255)), cnt + 1
      from t join
           nums
           on nums.n > t.n 
     )
 select *
 from t;
```

There may be a similar method using `connect by`, but I am more familiar with recursive CTEs.

Comment: [CROSS JOIN fails in Oracle, but INNER JOIN works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38440). Also, if numbers are not unique, this query may not give full result.

Comment: @EatÅPeach . . . I admit that I did not test this on Oracle (I tested it on Postgres), but I fixed the answer.  The OP's question does not have duplicate values.  If there are, it is easily fixed by simply enumerating them and using the enumeration rather than the value itself when appending a "bigger" value.